# Getting an EhCache instance with Spring... intelligently

Tags: spring, ehcache

I need to get a specific EhCache instance by name and I'd prefer to autowire if possible. Given the following automatically configured controller, how can I autowire in the cache instance I'm looking for?

```
@Controller 
public class MyUniqueService {
    ...
}
```

---

```
<beans ...>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="my.controllers"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

How do I configure EhCache in my application context? I don't see any log messages from EhCache about it loading the ehcache.xml file in my `/WEB-INF/` directory. How do I make it load it?

How can I integrate EhCache with my Spring application to have it load the `ehcache.xml` file from my `/WEB-INF/` directory and autowire a cache by a given name into my `MyUniqueService` controller?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First you need to create a Ehcache CacheManager singleton  in you app context like this:

```
<bean id="myEhCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:my-ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Here `configLocation` is set to load from classpath or use `value="/WEB-INF/my-ehcache.xml"`.

In your controller simply inject the `CacheManager` instance:

```
@Controller 
public class MyUniqueService {

    @Resource(name="myEhCacheManager")
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to go the "entirely autowired" route, do:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Setup your class like so:

```
@Controller
public class MyUniqueService { 

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;

    public org.springframework.cache.Cache getUniqueObjectCache() {
        return cacheManager.getCache("uniqueObjectCache");
    }
}
```

`uniqueObjectCache` corresponds to this cache instance in your `ehcache.xml` cache definition:

```
<cache name="uniqueObjectCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       transactionalMode="off"/>
```

There isn't a way to inject an actual cache instance, but as shown above, you can inject a cache manager and use it to get the cache you're interested in.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you have cacheManager defined:

```
<bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

You can get/inject specific cache like this:

```
@Value("#{cacheManager.getCache('myCacheName')}")
private Cache myCache;
```

See also examples how to use Spring EL inside the `@Value()` http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-method-invocation-example/ if you are interested.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use autowire if the context can find a bean with the correct class.  Here is how I configured my xml

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>WEB-INF/ehcache.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cache" class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache" factory-bean="cacheManager" factory-method="getCache">
    <constructor-arg value="CacheNameHere" />          
</bean>
```

And my java class

```
@Autowired
private net.sf.ehcache.Cache cache;
```

This setup works for me.

Comment: @ClintonBosch - If you have more than one, you just use `@Qualifier('cacheBeanId')` with `@Autowired`

Answer (score 9):

Indeed! Or if you want to use a java config class:

```
        @Inject
        private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
            try {
                ehCacheCacheManager.setCacheManager(ehcacheCacheManager().getObject());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create an EhCacheManagerFactoryBean", e);
            }
            return ehCacheCacheManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public FactoryBean<net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager> ehcacheCacheManager() {
            EhCacheManagerFactoryBean bean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
            bean.setConfigLocation(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:ehcache.xml"));
            return bean;
        }
```