# Web caching and Spring WebMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, ehcache

Is this a duplicate of [11427666](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427666/web-page-caching-in-spring-3-1-webmvc)? Not quite.

Our JSP pages take quite a long time to render (> 200ms) because of many many translated fragments and the resulting calls to the message source. I can imagine to remove the moving parts (load them with AJAX afterwards), so the pages will be static – except from the locale that still depends on the user that is logged in.

I looked at [Ehache and web caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching) which looks promising. However, it is a simple filter, depending on the URL only.

How would I combine the two? Interceptor, filter?

Comment: I may not be fully understanding, but could you use the Ehcache web cache filter idea (or similar) using the URL + locale as a cache key?

Comment: As I understood, the filter gets into the picture too early – we get the locale from the session. How can I access the session at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use the standard servlet filter due to the need for session data, seems to me that you'd want to use some sort of taglib within your JSP in order to cache the entire page...resulting in 1 single cache lookup based on "url+locale".
In your JSP, that'd be something like:

```
<cache:ehcache> 
you page text...more text...
message bundle lookup etc...
more text
etc...
</cache:ehcache>
```

The bad news: I don't think this taglib exists already...

But the good news: I don't think it'd be too hard at all to build.

And if you do, you could share it, as I'm sure there are many others who'd be interested.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering of jsp static fragments should be almost instantaneous as these are compiled to byte code.  Is the 200ms rendering time from your local machine or from a server?

Comment: Both. The time is so high because the page contains so much stuff. Not really computationally expensive, rather it’s the more than 50 text fragments that get translated by looking up the code in a `MessageSource`. Even a fast message source is a bit slow here.

Comment: is the messageSource loading from disk on each lookup, or it cached in memory?

Comment: Not anymore. Just assume it’s fast. It may be any other kind of computation that must be performed but is static for a long time. Valid for the whole day for instance or at least for the user session. We do lots of caching in the background already.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few approaches to integrate the two:

- [Getting an EhCache instance with Spring... intelligently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462662/1113772)
- [Caching Methods with Spring 3 Annotations](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/recipes/spring-annotations.html)
- [Using Spring and BigMemory Go](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/spring)

**References**

- [Ehcache 2.6.x Documentation (PDF)](http://ehcache.org/files/documentation/ehcache-2.6.x-documentation.pdf)
- [ehcache-spring-annotations github repo](https://github.com/google-code-export/ehcache-spring-annotations)

Comment: This answer is not to the point and assumes the OP did not do his homework.