# Cache duplication in specific Spring configuration

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have two tomcat servers in the cluster and I want to duplicate the cache in the cluster (same cache in each server). How I can do that with Ehcache and JGroups/RMI using the following configuration (without defining a cache):

1.Context configuration:

```
<bean id="myEhCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:my-ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

2.Controller:

```
@Controller 
public class MyUniqueService {

    @Resource(name="myEhCacheManager")
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    ...
}
```

This configuration is mentioned here:
[Getting an EhCache instance with Spring... intelligently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462662/getting-an-ehcache-instance-with-spring-intelligently)

Thanks a lot

Comment: what exactly is meant by duplicate cache?

Comment: do you want to save the cached data or do you want to save the cache to an other cache=

Comment: Thanks, I have a cluster with two AS and I want to have the same cache in each server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To duplcate the cache on other server the configuration can be as follow :

```
<ehcache>
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
                                 properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=${other sharinr server cache url}"/>
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                 properties="hostName=localhost,port=xxx, remoteObjectPort=xxx, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>


 <cache name="MY_CACHE"
     maxEntriesLocalHeap=""
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds=""
     timeToLiveSeconds=""
     maxEntriesLocalDisk=""
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds=""
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">

 <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
                             properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true,
          replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true "/>
</cache>
</ehcache>
```