# Updating Cache in spring/Spring boot

Tags: caching, spring-boot

I am working with Spring boot project and I want to implement a cache which will be taking data from a db and my api will directly contact with cache.My requirement  is before Cache expires it should try to reload new data(Auto Refresh).If It gets reloaded successfully it should evict old data else retain old data and try to refresh after some time.I am trying to do this with ehcache.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: here [getting-an-ehcache-instance-with-spring-intelligently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462662/getting-an-ehcache-instance-with-spring-intelligently)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cache Event Listeners](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/apis/cache-event-listeners.html). You could write your own listener that fetches the data when the `notifyElementExpired` method gets called.